# Which year Tour de France had riders from most countries?

Tags: trivia, cycling, tour-de-france

The riders that competed in the 2016 Tour de France represented 35 different countries. And the riders that are competing in the 2017 Tour de France are from 32 different countries.[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_teams_and_cyclists_in_the_2017_Tour_de_France#By_nationality)

But my question is which year Tour de France had competing riders representing most number of countries?